# C # Linq SelectMany, TypeScript Equivalent

Tags: javascript, c#, linq

How can I write **SelectMany**, which is a Linq function in C#, to do the same in TypeScript language.

For Example, The output of the sample code is as follows:

```
string[] letter = { "a", "b", "c" };
int[] number = { 1, 2, 3 };
var result = letter.SelectMany(x => number, (x, y) => (x + y));
```

result = *a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3*

How can I write the typescript equivalent of this code. I try this but it doesn't work.

`const result = letter.reduce((x, y) => [...x, ...y], number);`

Can you help me, Thanks.

Comment: This is not a TypeScript question so I have retagged it as JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

C# `SelectMany` corresponds to Typescript's `flatMap`, scala's `flatMap` and haskell's `bind`. Idea comes from concept called **Monad** from category theory.

### With flatMap

```js
const letters: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const numbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3]
const result = letters.flatMap((letter) => numbers.map((n) => `${letter}${n}`))

console.log(result)
// OUTPUT
// [
//   'a1', 'a2', 'a3',
//   'b1', 'b2', 'b3',
//   'c1', 'c2', 'c3'
// ]
```

### With reduce

```js
const letters: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const numbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3]
const result = letters.reduce<string[]>((p, c) => [...p, ...numbers.map((n) => `${c}${n}`)], [])

console.log(result)
// OUTPUT
// [
//   'a1', 'a2', 'a3',
//   'b1', 'b2', 'b3',
//   'c1', 'c2', 'c3'
// ]
```

Comment: +1: `flatMap` is indeed the analogous member. `reduce` can certainly do the same work, but that is also true of `Enumerable.Aggregate` whose analog is `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a TypeScript library for LINQ.

It is called **ts-generic-collections-linq**.

Providing strongly-typed, queryable collections such as:

- List
- Dictionary

Easy to use.

NPM

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-generic-collections-linq

Sample linq query:

```js
let result = ownerPets.selectMany(x => x.pets);
```